# System.Web.UI.Page override InitializeCulture and access MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm currently experiencing a weird problem. First of all my code snipped:

```
// This is my base page class
public class MyBasePage
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        base.InitializeCulture();
        MasterPage master = Page.Master; // point1
    }
}

// This is my page
public partial class Default : MyBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         label1.Text = "Test"; // point2
    }
}
```

Usally, label1 on point2 is not NULL. But if I access the masterpage in the InitializeCulture() event (point1), it is. Has someone an explantation why?

I guess I have to find another workaround, which is okay for me. But I would like to understand what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

That's because master page and themes are applied to the page during initialization, and InitializeCulture is called before that, so it returns null.

Comment: I think you missunderstood. The Page.Master is not null. But the label1 will get null in the Page_OnLoad if the master was accessed in the InitializeCulture

Comment: You should not access MasterPage in the InitializeCulture in the first place. It's not populated yet, so it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I analysed the behaviour with ILSpy. The problem is, that the masterpage isn't initialized in the InitializeCulture-event and if accessed, it will get initialized - but obviously not correct.

Conclusion: Never access the masterpage from the InitializeCulture event - it will mess up the page-initialisation-process.

Here, just for information, the .NET code which initializes the masterpage:

```
internal static MasterPage CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
{
    MasterPage masterPage = null;
    if (masterPageFile == null)
    {
        if (contentTemplateCollection != null && contentTemplateCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Content_only_allowed_in_content_page"));
        }
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        VirtualPath virtualPath = VirtualPathProvider.CombineVirtualPathsInternal(owner.TemplateControlVirtualPath, masterPageFile);
        ITypedWebObjectFactory typedWebObjectFactory = (ITypedWebObjectFactory)BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(context, virtualPath);
        if (!typeof(MasterPage).IsAssignableFrom(typedWebObjectFactory.InstantiatedType))
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Invalid_master_base", new object[]
            {
                masterPageFile
            }));
        }
        masterPage = (MasterPage)typedWebObjectFactory.CreateInstance();
        masterPage.TemplateControlVirtualPath = virtualPath;
        if (owner.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control control in owner.Controls)
            {
                LiteralControl literalControl = control as LiteralControl;
                if (literalControl == null || Util.FirstNonWhiteSpaceIndex(literalControl.Text) >= 0)
                {
                    throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Content_allowed_in_top_level_only"));
                }
            }
            owner.Controls.Clear();
        }
        if (owner.Controls.IsReadOnly)
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("MasterPage_Cannot_ApplyTo_ReadOnly_Collection"));
        }
        if (contentTemplateCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (string text in contentTemplateCollection.Keys)
            {
                if (!masterPage.ContentPlaceHolders.Contains(text.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                {
                    throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("MasterPage_doesnt_have_contentplaceholder", new object[]
                    {
                        text,
                        masterPageFile
                    }));
                }
            }
            masterPage._contentTemplates = contentTemplateCollection;
        }
        masterPage._ownerControl = owner;
        masterPage.InitializeAsUserControl(owner.Page);
        owner.Controls.Add(masterPage);
        return masterPage;
    }
}
```